# Can I post a predefined message to a user's wall on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a website page for a contest which involves users to post a specific message on their wall with a specific hashtag in order to be entered. I was looking through the JavaScript API for ways to post a preset message to their wall. I want to create a one click button, just like Twitter does, where you click a button, login and then click 'post' to post the message. Is there any way to do this?

I looked at some things but the publish stream is deprecated and no longer allows to specify a message.

I would really appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read https://developers.facebook.com/policy . Especially 2.3: "Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments, and captions"